# Issue in PDF generation of a LWC component in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, pdf

Does anybody done pdf generation by means of LWC(with Visualforce page). I have done following code and it is working fine, until renderAs comes. If anybody knows a solution/workaround, please let me know. PFB code snippet below:

**LWC - helloWorld**

```
<template>
    Hello World
</template>
```

**helloWorldApp - for dependency**

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="c:helloWorld"/>
</aura:application>
```

HelloWorldPdf - Visualforce page

```
<apex:page renderAs="PDF">
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:helloWorldApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:helloWorld",     {}  ,       
              "lightning",
              function(cmp) {
                // do some stuff
              }
          );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PDF renderer does not support JavaScript, but Aura and LWC components are always loaded via JavaScript. That means it is impossible to use renderAs to render an Aura Component or LWC component in to a PDF. There is no workaround to this limitation. You'll need to write the full code in Visualforce if you want to be able to render the page as a PDF.

Comment: I got a link, which works for smaller text(by pushing text to vf page at runtime) - https://gist.github.com/toanshulverma/16244d19ac68364cb75443695d81403b

However this is not a full-proof solution(and restricted to 135Kb(view state)),

Comment: Since it is not directly possibly by W20, marking this answer as accepted. thanks for your time!

Comment: @YsrShk Actually, the view state doesn't need to be limited to 135k if you're clever with the design, but in principle, you still wouldn't be able to render Lightning Components this way, because the renderer doesn't support custom components, either, only plain HTML. Hopefully, we'll get a solution in the future, but for now, Visualforce is what we're left with.

Comment: Understood the crux(with lightning components). Hope so, we'll get a new PDF generation tool (since old one has lots of limitations).

Comment: It's really awkward to ask the same question again after 2+ years. But, guys is there any alternative of renderas pdf OR converting the vf page into PDF?

Comment: @PraveenBehera [Light DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_light_dom) can allow you to use third-party PDF tools like jspdf to render a component and all its children. It will still be limited to context (e.g. you can't use it in an email), but it may be just what you're looking for.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the comment. I went through but I think it does not print the HTML. it only print data manipulated using JS, right?

Comment: @sfdcfox Hi Sorry to nudge you on this, Is there a way to connect (or) store VF Rendered PDF on a record , by clicking a button on LWC template, because problem am facing is, PDF is rendering only 1st page when viewed through mobile App.

Comment: @AjaySFDC Should be possible. `Page.myVfPageName.getContent()` would return a blob containing the PDF, and it should work just fine.